# do i need to fully download the blockchain before operating commands on litecoin daemon or dash daemon

Tags: json-rpc, litecoin, synchronization, daemon

I am setting up a website that needs to process commands like creating new addresses, do transactions even maintain wallet balance and get notifications on incoming transactions to address created. I want to use RPC but i see that it is not working as expected. I want to know if i need to fully synchronise the blockchain for the daemon to work and also how to force synchronise lite coin daemon via command line. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out we only need to sync to download new transactions rest we can add listen=0 to keep band-with minimum and continue as usual without contributing.

transactions anyway are broadcasted by node and will be visible in the network.